Chapter 2 proposition 2.6 Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry
This may be dumb but I don’t really understand what we are saying.
Hartshorne claims:
Let $V$ be a variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $\mathcal{O}_V$ be its sheaf of regular functions.
We will show that $(t(V),\alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_V))$ is a scheme over $k$
Since any variety can be covered by open affine subvarieties, it will be sufficient to show that if $V$ is affine, then $(t(V),\alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_V))$ is a scheme.
Why proving this will prove the first claim we have done?

It's a bit handwavy since there's more to check, but there is a gluing result for schemes where several spaces and structure sheaves on those spaces along with compatible data of space homeomorphisms and sheaf isomorphisms allows you to "glue" it all together into one space and one suitable sheaf, which you can then check is a scheme. But here you would have to know that the affine schemes $(t(U),\alpha_\ast(\mathcal{O}_U))$ will produce compatible gluing data as you cover $V$ with its affine subvarieties $U$

First, $(t(V), \alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_V))$ is obviously a ringed space.
Now take some open affine subvariety $U\subseteq V$ of $V$.
Let $\iota: U \to V$ be the inclusion. Then $t(\iota): t(U) \to t(V)\setminus t(V\setminus U), A \mapsto \bar A$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $A \mapsto A\cap U$.
Then the restriction $(t(V), \alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_V))|_{t(V)\setminus t(V\setminus U)}$ is isomorphic (as a ringed space!) to $(t(U), \alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_U))$ via $(t(\iota),\alpha_* \iota^*)$, which we know is a ($k$-)scheme since $U$ is affine. Thus the ringed space $(t(V), \alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_V))$ has an open covering by affine schemes and is therefore a ($k$-)scheme.

I’m missing something really stupid. I know our goal is to see a variety as a scheme, but I can’t see right now why even an affine variety is a $k$-scheme. Using the notations of Hartshorne, what would be the morphism from $U$ to $k$? Some kind of evaluation of polynomials?

@Francesco A $k$-scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is nothing but a scheme together with a morphism $(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \text{Spec}(k)$. But every such morphism comes from a unique morphism of rings $k \to \mathcal{O}X(X)$. In the above case $\alpha(\mathcal{O}_U)(t(U)) = \mathcal{O}_U(U)$ is a $k$-algebra, so take for the ringhomomorphism $k \to \mathcal{O}U(U) = \alpha(\mathcal{O}_U)(t(U))$ the natural one. This induces the $k$-scheme structure (exactly the same works for $V$ instead of $U$!). The above correspondence is Exercise $2.4$ of Chapter II in Hartshorne.
